# What do orange (normal eggs) do in Salmon Run?

Tags: splatoon-2

In Salmon Run you need golden eggs to progress through the game.

But everything gives you orange, normal eggs.

The smaller eggs are counted at the end of the game, but don't seem to give anything. They don't get converted to golden eggs, boost your score, or have a separate rewards track.

They don't seem to do anything during the game either.

So what is their use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The job score is the number of Golden Eggs the team collected, plus the whole number of Power Eggs divided by 200. This number is then multiplied based on each player's pay grade multiplier to form the final "Grizzco points" which are then added to see if the player earns a bonus for their work from Mr. Grizz

In the example shown below, the team collected 48 golden eggs and 1978 power eggs (the orange ones). The whole part of 1978/200 is 9. The job score is thus 48 + 9 = 57.

[image]

Source, [Splatoon wikia](https://splatoon.fandom.com/wiki/Salmon_Run).